# I have a navbar with two logos - the one which is not the navbar-brand should stay in-line with the button for collapsing while the menu collapses

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

As the title says I have a bootstrap navbar with two images. One is the navbar brand and the other is just a normal image.
I want the second image to be outside of the collapse menu - that is easy, I just didn't put it in that div.
But now when the menu appears, it gets pushed down after the menu.
Here are some photos. The first phone represents the position of the second image (and that's where I want it to stay), and the other is where it gets pushed down.
[image: 1]
[image: 2]

I've tried to move the second image before the navbar-collapse div. It works, but in the default state (where there is no button for collapsing) my logos stay on the left of the menu. (and that's not what I want). I tried some combinations with pull-right, pull-left, float positioning, etc. and nothing work.

The only thing I can think of and might work is absolute positioning inside relative positioning, but I don't think that this is the best solution.

Here is how my code looks (django template, using bootstrap):

```
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
<header>
    <div class="container-fluid border">
        <div class="row bg-orange">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="ml-1 margin-top-bot float-left">
                        <div class="phone">
                            <i class="fas fa-phone ml-5"></i>
                            <span class="ml-1 bara-mica-text">074 444 4444</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="email">
                            <i class="fas fa-envelope ml-5"></i>
                            <span class="ml-1 bara-mica-text">bestdavnic73@gmail.com</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mr-2 margin-top-bot float-right">
                      <span class="mr-5"><a href="#" class="mr-5">Login</a></span>
                      <span class="mr-5"><a href="#" class="mr-5">Register</a></span>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-custom navbar-light navbar-custom">     
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                  <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img src="{% static 'img/logo.jpg' %}" class="logo"></a>
                  <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item mr-2 active">
                      <a class="nav-link buton-top-home" href="/">Acasa <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item mr-2">
                      <a class="nav-link buton-top-home" href="#">Cine suntem?</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item mr-2">
                        <a class="nav-link buton-top-home" href="#">Cum te sustinem?</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item mr-2">
                      <a class="nav-link buton-top-home" href="#">Proiect 1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item mr-2">
                        <a class="nav-link buton-top-home" href="#">Proiect 2</a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item mr-2">
                          <a class="nav-link buton-top-home" href="#">Consultanta</a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item mr-2">
                        <a class="nav-link buton-top-home" href="#">Mediere</a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item mr-2">
                        <a class="nav-link buton-top-home" href="#">Portofoliu</a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item mr-2">
                          <a class="nav-link buton-top-home" href="#">FAQ</a>
                        </li>
                      <li class="nav-item mr-2">
                          <a class="nav-link buton-top-home" href="#">Contact</a>
                      </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="logos-top-wrapper">
                  <img src="{% static 'img/logos.jpg' %}" class="logos-top">
                </div>
              </nav> 
        </div>
    </header>
{% endblock %}
```

So, how can I make the "logos-top" img stay on the same level as the navbar-collapse button even if the menu collapses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the second image before the navbar-collapse div like you did first, and then to resolve the logos being on the left menu, add the `order: n` CSS style and a media break point to change the order when the menu collapses.

```
.order-logos {
        order: 1;
}

@media (max-width: 992px) {
        .order-logos {
                order: 0;
        }
}
```